# .NetCore MVC deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

In a .netcore application, I would like to offer the following (simplified):

```
// Create a new record, assume it returns an ID=1
https://site/MyController/Save?FirstName=John&LastName=Doe&Status=Active

// Update the record without full state
PUT https://site/MyController/1
{
  'DOB': '1/1/1970',
  'Status': null
}
```

I would like to translate this second call to:

```
UPDATE MyModel SET DOB = '1/1/1970' AND Status=NULL WHERE Id = 1
```

I can certainly code my `Create` method in `MyController` to parse the request (querystring/form/body) for the submitted values, and create my SQL accordingly.

However, I'd prefer to follow MVC conventions and leverage the binding that MVC offers out of the box:

```
public async Task<MyModel> Save(string id, [FromBody]MyModel instance)
{
  await _MyRepository.UpdateAsync(id, message);
  return message;
}
```

The problem here is that instance will look like this:

```
{
  'FirstName': null,
  'LastName': null,
  'DOB': '1/1/1970',
  'Status': null
}
```

At which point I **cannot determine which fields should be NULLed** in the Db, and which should be left alone.

I've implemented a wrapper class that:

- upon deserialization, sets any 'dirty' properties, and
- upon serialization, only writes dirty properties

This would change my method signature a bit, but not impose a burden on developers:

```
public async Task<MyModel> Save(string id, [FromBody]MyWrapper<MyModel> wrapper
{
  await _MyRepository.UpdateAsync(id, wrapper.Instance, wrapper.DirtyProperties);
  return wrapper.Instance;
}
```

My two questions are:

1. Am I **re-inventing an established pattern**?
2. Can I **intercept the MVC deserialzation** (in an elegant manner)?

Comment: Don't use persistence models as return or input values of controller actions. It screams for trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look into custom model binding.

- create own model binder: class that implements IModelBinder interface:

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Defines an interface for model binders.
  /// </summary>
  public interface IModelBinder
  {
     /// <summary>
     /// Attempts to bind a model.
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="bindingContext">The <see cref="ModelBindingContext"/>.</param>
     /// <returns>
     /// <para>
     /// A <see cref="Task"/> which will complete when the model binding process completes.
     /// </para>
     /// <para>
     /// If model binding was successful, the <see cref="ModelBindingContext.Result"/> should have
     /// <see cref="ModelBindingResult.IsModelSet"/> set to <c>true</c>.
     /// </para>
     /// <para>
     /// A model binder that completes successfully should set <see cref="ModelBindingContext.Result"/> to
     /// a value returned from <see cref="ModelBindingResult.Success"/>. 
     /// </para>
     /// </returns>
     Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext);
   }
  ```
- register your binder:

  ```
  services.AddMvc().Services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
      options.ModelBinders.Insert(0, new YourCustomModelBinder());
  });
  ```

[MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions/ModelBinding/IModelBinder.cs) github repo and "[Custom Model Binding](http://intellitect.com/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-1-0/)" article may help:

Comment: This does indeed achieve what I've asked for. However, it also leaves me tempted to merely create Middleware, since I'm (so far) leveraging very little of MVC's value-adds. Which, of course, contradicts my question!

Answer (score 0):

The PUT verb requires the whole entity, but you can send an HTTP PATCH with a delta. There is little official documentation on exactly HOW this is done, but I did find this [link](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-json-patch-partial-api-updates) that lays out how to accomplish this with a JSONPatchDocument that does basically what your intercepting class does.

Comment: Elegant from the server-side perspective! For my use cases, I'm trying to make life simple for the client / consumer, and getting them to adopt the rather verbose PATCH document will be a challenge. [link](http://jsonpatch.com/)